# How to specify a SQL product in file headers

Tags: postgresql, emacs

In emacs I can specify that a file is SQL using this notation:

```
-- -*- mode: SQL -*-
```

But there are specific sub modes for SQL: postgresql, mysql, ansi, etc. I can set the product using the emacs menu when I open a file. But I want to put something in the header to help emacs select the product automatically. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-*- sql-product: ansi; -*-

or

-*- sql-product: mysql; -*-

etc.